# Session error for requests_oauthlib oauth method

Tags: python, oauth, flask

I am using `requests_oauthlib` `OAuth2Session` for getting oauth from Github API.
When I access the token authorization url and the state of the request and saving it in session, it is not actually executing the statement. During the callback URL processing, it is displaying error like:

> 'oauth_state' not defined

My code is:

```
@app.route("/")
def demo():
    """Step 1: User Authorization.

    Redirect the user/resource owner to the OAuth provider (i.e. Github)
    using an URL with a few key OAuth parameters.
    """
    github = OAuth2Session(client_id)
    authorization = list(github.authorization_url(authorization_base_url))

    # State is used to prevent CSRF, keep this for later.
    global state
    state = authorization[1]
    return redirect(authorization[0])

@app.route('/support',methods=["GET"])
def support():
    global state
    github = OAuth2Session(client_id,state=state)
    #token = github.fetch_token(token_url,client_secret=client_secret, authorization_response=request.url)

    #session['oauth_token'] = token

    return "Request url is %s AND STATE stored in session is %s" % (request.url, state)
```

Please help me solving this error in retrieving the `oauth_state` for callback url processing so that my app works fine.

Comment: Why don't you use `session['oauth_state']` instead of `state`? See [this](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) example.

Comment: Where is `authorization_base_url` defined?

Comment: authorization base url is from github api. it is defined in the main fucntion.